# Unable to Restore the Backup File in PgAdmin4

Tags: admin, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin-4

I have been using "PgAdmin 4" and i am unable to restore the backup file. it gives me an error 
"object of type 'bool' has no len() pgadmin restore"
My Log file detail is given below :

```
"2018-08-01 11:06:38,943: ERROR pgadmin:    object of type 'bool' has no len()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\tools\restore\__init__.py", line 327, in create_restore_job
    *args
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\tools\restore\__init__.py", line 84, in __init__
    if arg and len(arg) >= 2 and arg[:2] == '--':
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
2018-08-01 11:08:58,861: ERROR  pgadmin:    object of type 'bool' has no len()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\tools\restore\__init__.py", line 327, in create_restore_job
    *args
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\tools\restore\__init__.py", line 84, in __init__
    if arg and len(arg) >= 2 and arg[:2] == '--':
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()  "
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you running the latest version of pgAdmin4?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I tried to restore a TAR file created by own pg Admin. To solve this problem I needed to rename the file with a ".tar" in the end of file (example: my-backup.tar).

I though this very strange, in spite of himself had generated the file.